# iOS Saving UIImage from UIImagePickerController in app

Tags: ios, serialization, uiimageview, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I have an app where I pick an image using `UIImagePickerController`. I want to save this image in the app and use to populate a set of `UIImageView`s. The app is universal. Once user selects the image, it is used as an image in a `UITableViewCell` as the `contentView`'s `UIImage` as a square image that takes up the entire `contentView`

The questions I have are

- How do I handle resolution? Does `UIImageView` and its scaling properties handle it or do I have to up/down rez based on Display Scale and Trait Collection?
- How does `UIImageAsset` play into this? Is it necessary to use?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle resolution, it is in your hands. You can resize the image if you want to. `UIImageView` will only handle how the image appears to the user, but it will not alter the image size.

`UIImageAsset` has nothing to do in this scenario.

**From Documentation:**

> A common use case for **UIImageAsset** is the grouping of multiple images
>   of the same item at different display scales.

For more explanation about [UIImageAsset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25716128/how-to-use-create-and-use-a-uiimageasset-in-ios-8).

After you select the image from the picker, you store in your data source and you  reload the tableview to display the new image.

Comment: @MrT Correct me I'm wrong, you're saying the image stays the same size regardless of display or trait collection, but that I can use UIImageView's scaling to present it how I want? *If* I resized for each device, at that point would `UIImageAsset` be an option?

Comment: UIImageAsset can never be your option. It is the same thing as the image assets folder in your Xcode project.

Comment: Yes, regardless of size, image view displays the image and image stays in the same size unless u change it